# PDF Viewer works on VS Code Live Code Server but not on my local computer, pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, visual-studio-code, pdf.js

I am trying to make a PDF viewer, and it runs perfectly when I run it through live server on vscode, but for some reason, when I go to my files, right click on the index.html and click open with chrome, firefox, or internet explorer it comes up with 2 errors:

1)GET file://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:18 
2)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined
    at main.js:18

Here is my index.html code and my main.js code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF Viewer Attempt 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>PDF Name</h1>

    <div>
    <button id="prev">Previous</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;


    <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
    </div>

    <canvas id="the-pdf"></canvas>

    <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:
    //Code adapted from https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/

```
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf'; //works with this internet pdf
//url = 'pdf.pdf'; // Works with local pdf



// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];


// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
    pageNum = 1,
    pageRendering = false,
    pageNumPending = null,
    scale = 0.8,
    canvas = document.getElementById('the-pdf'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
 * @param num Page number.
 */
function renderPage(num) {
  pageRendering = true;
  // Using promise to fetch the page
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

    // Wait for rendering to finish
    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
      pageRendering = false;
      if (pageNumPending !== null) {
        // New page rendering is pending
        renderPage(pageNumPending);
        pageNumPending = null;
      }
    });
  });

  // Update page counters
  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
}

/**
 * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
 * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
 */
function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}

/**
 * Displays previous page.
 */
function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
 */
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

  // Initial/first page rendering
  renderPage(pageNum);
});
```

Any help is appreciated! This was my first post so let me know if there is anything I can do to format better! Dont worry about that line that says error for now, that is just a paragraph block.

Comment: You specified a protocol-relative URL to load the `pdf.js` resource from - but that of course can’t work, when you don’t access your document via `http://` or `https://` to begin with. So you need to add the protocol for that URL - or not test via the file system to begin with. (The latter could easily cause additional problems, if this needs to make any AJAX requests in the background, or something like that.)

Comment: @CBroe I am a little new to js, how can i learn to fix this?

Comment: @CBroe Update! I understand now, I just needed to add https to the beginning! What was that second part about not testing via the file system to begin with?

Comment: I am referring to the _“go to my files, right click on the index.html and click open with”_ part - that is not the context in which a website normally “runs”, and there are several restrictions that apply, when it comes to loading stuff in the background, etc. If at all possible, you should test stuff like this via a local web server.